# Unable to apply data patch: elasticsearch6

Tags: magento2, setup-upgrade, elasticsearch

> Unable to apply data patch Magento\CatalogSearch\Setup\Patch\Data\SetInitialSearchWeightForAttributes for module Magento_CatalogSearch. Original exception message: Indexer handler is not available: elasticsearch6

What is the best way to get either around this or fix this?

Note: I cannot get into my admin, I cannot run the `setup: upgrade` command as the message above halts the upgrade process. I have access to the config files and the database.

Version: Magento EE 2.3.3

Comment: You can try switch to mysql and in time find solution for your error Just run php -f bin/magento config:set catalog/search/engine 'mysql'.  And reindex now and setup:upgrade

Comment: I went to my config.php and switched the search engine from elasticsearch to mysql. No luck as when I try to s:up I still get the same error, and this: bin/magento app:config:import
Processing configurations data from configuration file...
Import failed: The store that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again.

Comment: Try to disable thirds party modules to be sure that they not causing this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this, on a Mac, with ElasticSearch installed through homebrew.

Before this error, I always saw the following errors in the var/log/system.log:

```
[2023-05-04T12:35:33.520048+00:00] report.ERROR: Sample Data error: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"cluster_block_exception","reason":"index [acom246_product_1_v1] blocked by: [TOO_MANY_REQUESTS/12/disk usage exceeded flood-stage watermark, index has read-only-allow-delete block];"}],"type":"cluster_block_exception","reason":"index [acom246_product_1_v1] blocked by: [TOO_MANY_REQUESTS/12/disk usage exceeded flood-stage watermark, index has read-only-allow-delete block];"},"status":429} [] []
```

The `disk usage exceeded flood-stage watermark` error occurred when I still have 897 GB of available disk space.
This resolved my issue:

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/_cluster/settings?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "persistent": {
    "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.low": "90%",
    "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.high": "95%",
    "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.flood_stage": "97%"
  }
}
'
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/*/_settings?expand_wildcards=all&pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null
}
'
```

Source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/fix-common-cluster-issues.html